# Implement "WITH .. AS" Statements in Airflow Dags

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, amazon-athena

In Amazon Athena UI, I can do something like this:

```
WITH outer_query AS (SELECT id FROM outer)
SELECT * FROM inner JOIN ON inner.id = outer_query.id
```

How do I do this in Dags in Airflow using Python? The examples I saw uses simple queries using PythonOperator and doesn't use the WITH .. AS .. statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `AthenaOperator`
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/athena.html#run-a-query-in-amazon-athena

and you can use the `WITH ... AS` syntax in Athena
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html